# Java is giving me a different buffer of the same packet from the one in C

Tags: java, sockets, networking, buffer

Hello StackOverflow community,

I has always been around this community for a while but I never had such a problem without any other solution online, or at least, I couldn't find it.

I'm using Java to make a client, as soon as the client connects to the server, it receives a packet containing sensible and essential informations and of course they are encrypted; I successfully reverse engineered the cryptography behind the whole process a long time ago and implemented it in C++ without any problem and fully tested with positive results.

Now I'm trying to rewrite the client in Java for science and better coding speed, but the only problem is that the packet is different from what it should look like.
For example, by sniffing the packet with a C native application I get a buffer, but the same packet in my Java client results different.
What do I mean? I mean there are several 0xFD/BF bytes around which are not valid, resulting in a corrupted buffer and then a decryption failure.

These are the screenshots to let you understand better

Original **CORRECT** packet
[Corrent packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoGEP.png)

This is the packet dumped by Java, which is **CORRUPTED**
[Incorrect packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HglZj.png)

I'm using Read as reading object class for the socket's outStream.
Do you have any idea about the cause of the problem?

```js
private Reader _br = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

char[] _data = new char[92];
this._br.read(_data);

_dump(toBytes(_data));
```

I just put the code related to the issue.

Comment: My crystal ball isn't working today.  You'll have to show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are decoding random bytes (probably your ciphertext) to characters, using the platform default encoding, which appears to be UTF-8.

This generally doesn't work, of course, so the replacement character, "�" or U+FFFD, is substituted in the character stream wherever invalid byte sequences are encountered.

Then you print the characters, encoding the (now-corrupted) text into UTF-8. The UTF-8 encoding of U+FFFD is 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD.

The cause of the problem is that you are treating non-textual data as text.

---

*Update:*

The problem is that you are creating an `InputStreamReader`. Don't do that. That would only be useful if the input stream contains encoded text. Read your input into a byte array instead:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[92];
for (int pos = 0; pos < data.length; ) {
  int n = is.read(data, pos, data.length - pos);
  if (n < 0)
    throw new EOFException();
  pos += n;
}
/* Print what you read for debugging... */
for (byte b : data)
  System.out.printf("%02X", b & 0xFF);
System.out.println();
```

Now `data` contains your packet. You can parse it and decrypt the ciphertext. Perhaps the resulting plain text is actually text, and at that point, you can decode it into characters.

Comment: Uhm, seems a valid reason, is there a hint you can give me to print non-unicode characters and valid for single bytes printing in a for loop?

Comment: @d3vil401 I don't really understand your question, but I tried to guess. See my update.

Comment: You gave me exactly what I needed, thanks really much!